# How can use sqlite update via ContentValues when want to update depend on current value and how can retrieve the Result?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I've a situation in sqlite that make you an example: My table has two fields,"_id" and "_score" . I have a record with _id=1, _score=10. I want to update this row to 5 number more than the current value(10). in SQL i can do it simple like:

```
Update my_table set _score = _score + 5 where _id = 1
```

but in sqlite I have these that I don't know how can fix it to what I want :

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("_score", my_value);
SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH + DB_NAME, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
int id = db.update(MY_TABLE,values,"_id = ?",new String[]{String.valueOf(my_id)});
```

and the Other problem is the returned value. I think in above example I give

```
id = 1
```

for 1 row effected. but I want to know that: Is there any way to retrieve the value of updated column(in my example I want to give "15"). Some thing like in SQL server that we fetch from

```
"@@ROWCOUNT" or "@@fetch_status"
```

Hope to describe it well. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android's `update()` function can set only fixed values.

To execute your SQL statement, you have to use `execSQL()`:

```
db.execSQL("Update my_table set _score = _score + 5 where _id = 1");
```

In SQLite, the UPDATE statement does not return any data (except the count of affected rows). To get the old or new data, you have to execute a SELECT separately.

Comment: Thank you @CL. very useful.

Answer (score -1):

For your first problem about updating the score value try this:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("_score", my_value);
SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH + DB_NAME, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
int id = db.update(my_table, values, _id + " = ?",
        new String[] { String.valueOf(my_id) });
}
```

Comment: Nothing, but no effect